# How to make a Discord bot skip the join VC step when the play music command comes in

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to see if it's already in a VC and skip the join step if it's already in a VC, this is the current code i have for it joining

```py
voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        await channel.connect()
```

Then the code afterwards is the download the audio and play etc, what do i add to make it skip the join part

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? The bot must "join" whenever the command is executed. Do you want to make the bot not join again if it is already in the channel?

Comment: @Dominik You are correct

Comment: Do you have a `join` command to test it? This gives out `ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.` - Is this not happening for you? Your specification is a bit fuzzy. If the bot is in a channel, should it stay there until the song is over, so that you can't get the bot into your channel by command if you are not in the bots voice channel?